# Tricky logarithmic problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is given that $\log_9 p = \log_{12} q = \log_{16} (p+q) $. Find the value of $q/p$. I can see that the bases have common factors, but I don't exactly know how to exploit that. I tried many approaches to this, but I couldn't get it. The farthest I got was probably $q/p=4/\sqrt{p}$ (if I remember right)  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let all of them equal to $x$. We then have
$$p=9^x; q = 12^x; p+q = 16^x$$
Hence, we need solutions for
$$9^x + 12^x = 16^x \implies 1 + \left(\dfrac43\right)^x = \left(\dfrac{16}9\right)^x$$
Now let $\left(\dfrac43 \right)^x = y$. We then have
$$y^2 = y+1 \implies y = \dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{p}q = \dfrac{12^x}{9^x} = \left(\dfrac43\right)^x = y = \dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$$

Comment: I.e. $p/q = {\text golden\ ratio}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We have that $9^{t}=p$ and  $12^{t}=q$ where $t=\log_9(p)=\log_{12}(q)$, so
$$\frac{q}{p}=\frac{12^t}{9^t}=\frac{4^t}{3^t}=\frac{(16^t)^{1/2}}{(9^t)^{1/2}}=\frac{\sqrt{p+q}}{\sqrt{p}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

For some $a$, we have $9^a=p$, $12^a=q$, and $16^a=p+q$. Note that $12^2=9\cdot 16$. It follows that $q^2=p(p+q)$.

Divide through by $p^2$, and let $x=\frac{q}{p}$. We find that $x^2-x-1=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had it in this form (except that I had the square root taken) but I didn't realize it was a quadratic.